# websocket catch data when reconnecting process?

Tags: javascript, http, tcp, websocket

websocket connection will auto close after a few minutes if server doesnot push data to client. I watch the close event, and reconnect websocket.

But reconnecting websocket will spend a few seconds. At the reconnecting time, if server send data, client will lose these data.

How should I do if I want to catch data when reconnecting websocket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache your data in server if websocket connection is in closed state. As soon as connection established push data to client.

For caching there are multiple options Redis - https://redis.io/ or memcached - https://memcached.org/

Comment: good idea, I will have a try. I just think about handing in client, it  make this difficult.

Comment: You don't have to handle anything on the client side it's just a event for data. All you have to do is make sure client will notify the server after getting the data so server can remove this from cache.